# Reverse order of objects inside RLMArray

Tags: ios, realm

I have been testing the possibilities to reverse the order of RLMArray with objects. 
I am aware that i can add the objects to NSArray and then add a reverseObjectEnumerator to that array but I want to continue using the RLMarray since some of the objects could be invalidated. They will remain as invalidated and throw error if added inside NSArray.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it stands, an `RLMArray` object is a direct mapping to how the objects are stored in Realm. If you try and change the ordering of the objects in there, that's literally how they will be stored on disk.

You're definitely making the right call trying to continue using the `RLMArray` though. Copying objects from an `RLMArray` to an `NSArray` will page in every object, which would be both a performance and memory hit.

The best thing I can recommend is to continue using the `RLMArray`, but use a method that abstracts and reverses the access to it.

```
@interface MyObject: RLMObject

@property RLMArray<ChildObject *><ChildObject> *children;
- (RLMObject *)childAtInvertedIndex:(NSInteger)index;

@end

@implementation MyObject

- (RLMObject *)childAtInvertedIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    NSInteger invertedIndex = (self.children.count - 1) - index;
    return self.children[invertedIndex];
}

@end
```

This way, you're still getting the benefits of accessing the objects from `RLMArray` directly, but you're able to control the order in which they are accessed. :)

Comment: Very smart. Regards

Comment: Thanks a lot Amro! :)

Comment: Thank you TiM it looks like a smart way to reverse, I will  try this approach.